# How to visit a website using an online proxy

Tags: proxy, file-download

How can I ***download a file when I visit the website using an online proxy server***?

I cannot visit some websites directly so I use the online proxy server as a workaround to that problem when needed. While I can browse certain websites using this method, I am still not able to download files from these sites even though I can connect to them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) as your proxy. It fires up a special copy of FireFox that runs through the Tor network and changes exit points randomly. You're then safe, anonymous, untraceable, unblockable (unless your network administrator blocks tor), and it works like a normal browser, so you can still download.